# getting entire stdout of multiprocess.Process and display it in realtime in the current console

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python 3 and the `multiprocessing` module. Is there any chance to grab the entire stdout and stderr of `multiprocessing.Process` and redirect it to the current `sys.stdout` of the calling process?

A common approach here on SO is to redirect it to a temporary stdout file. But they all focus on getting the stdout **after** the process got executed. I am trying to achieve both, displaying it in real time as well in the current console.

The subprocess module makes this much easier, on the other side, only the multiprocessing.Process allows me to pass certain objects to the 'function/process' without pickling the objects on my own.

Any hint is highly appreciated.